# EWS online meeting

Tags: xml, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

all. I need a help with exchange. I'd like to create online meeting by using EWS. Firstly, I created a S4B meeting and then, I try to create the online meeting in outlook. But I have the following error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Header>
<h:ServerVersionInfo MajorVersion="15" MinorVersion="20" MajorBuildNumber="1017" MinorBuildNumber="22" Version="V2018_01_08" xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
</s:Header>

<s:Body>
  <m:UpdateItemResponse xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
    <m:ResponseMessages>
      <m:UpdateItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Error">
        <m:MessageText>Set action is invalid for property.</m:MessageText>
        <m:ResponseCode>ErrorInvalidPropertySet</m:ResponseCode>
        <m:DescriptiveLinkKey>0</m:DescriptiveLinkKey>
        <m:MessageXml><t:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:IsOnlineMeeting"/></m:MessageXml>
        <m:Items/>
      </m:UpdateItemResponseMessage>
    </m:ResponseMessages>
  </m:UpdateItemResponse>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

As doc says: isOnlineMeeting property read-writable only for organizer's meeting, but I am organizer.

Comment: It looks like you trying to update a Meeting after you have created it ? have you tried setting that property at the time of creation ?

Comment: But I suppose a s4b and an outlook meeting don't depend on each other. And after create the s4b meeting I need to create an outlook meeting contains the url of the s4b meeting, right?

Comment: Yeah but i think you may find that property is only settable at the time of creation, hence why i would suggest you at least try that way.